# MS Access not prompting for changes despite setting DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Tags: ms-access, save, ms-access-2010, corruption

So I've set `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` but for some reason if I edit a query, it closes and saves without asking me to save. If I run a Maketable query, it runs without prompting for a confirmation. I'm not sure if there's a setting I am missing somewhere or if the database is corrupted, and if so, how can I fix it? I also tried a Compact and Repair but this didn't have any impact.

Comment: In your Access options, on the **Client Settings** tab, what do you have checked under **Confirm**? There should be 3 checkboxes (**Record Changes**, **Document Deletions**, and **Action queries**).

Comment: Are 3 are checked

Comment: What code are you using to do edits? Issuing warnings is default for RunSQL and OpenQuery. Why do you need to set True?

Comment: In this case I am not running code, just running a maketable query directly from the UI, or editing a query from the UI, etc. I just ran that code snippet just in case the setting had been set to False (I didn't know about the Client Settings tab until today, TIL!)

Comment: What you mean exactly when you say "running a maketable query directly from the UI, or editing a query from the UI, etc."?

Comment: As in, I run the maketable by clicking it directly in the navigation pane, or if I want to edit a query, right clicking it and going into the design view or SQL view, etc.